# Dealing with msi installation result

Tags: windows-installer, error-code

I have faced a problem with analyzing installation result of a single msi file. If a newer version of some program exits it returns code 1603 (installation failure), which is not actually an error. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a verbose log which will have more error detail:

```
msiexec -i setup.msi -l*v logfile.txt
```

Search for `return value 3` (localized) in the log file to get to the location of the error. The actual cause of the error is usually logged a few lines before that.

Comment: But this is human-related info, how can program to deal with that text? I just need something to detect if the error was critical (then abort installation) or not.

Comment: @Alek Now I understand your question better. Do you have created the MSI file or is it from another manufacturer? If it is your own you could write a custom action that returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS` in case that a newer version is installed. This would skip the installation but the installation process would still return 0 (success).

Comment: It is another manufacturer, in fact it can anything - like VS Redistributable Package or .Net installer

Comment: I'm afraid you can't handle this generically then. For things like VC Redist and .NET installer you can check for yourself if there already is the same or a newer version installed and in this case don't call the installers at all. The registry locations to check are fairly well documented.